# Difference between using tagname or e.target for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a line-through toggle when `li` is clicked.

The Only difference in below codes is javascript codes.

The problem is former one. The latter is working.

I can't find why former is not working when latter is working and written almost same.

not working code

```
()=>{
        li.classList.toggle("remove");
    }
```

working code

```
(e)=>{
        e.target.classList.toggle("remove");
    }
```

not working whole code

```js
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (li of lis){
    li.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        li.classList.toggle("remove");
    })
}
```

```css
.remove {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="sampleList">
      <li id="list1">list 1</li>
      <li id="list2">list 2</li>
      <li id="list3">list 3</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

working whole code

```js
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (li of lis){
    li.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        e.target.classList.toggle("remove");
    })
}
```

```css
.remove {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

    <ul id="sampleList">
      <li id="list1">list 1</li>
      <li id="list2">list 2</li>
      <li id="list3">list 3</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside the li click event listener you don't have access to the li variable. `this.classList.toggle("remove");` should work instead if the event was fired by the li element and not any of its children

Comment: Because you use global variable `li`, try this `for (let li of lis){`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this next approach for your first method to work.
You can loop through every one of the `Nodelist` items by setting `var i = 0` or `let i = 0` and then iterate over the NodeList'
s length.

Every time you would toggle a list item, you would be assigning a scoped `let` or `var` variable for a unique click on each item.

The loop => `for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)` or `for(let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)` and set the `classlist` of your `e.target` (event target).
That must do the work.

```js
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
  lis[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     e.target.classList.toggle("remove");
  });
}
```

```css
.remove {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="sampleList">
      <li id="list1">list 1</li>
      <li id="list2">list 2</li>
      <li id="list3">list 3</li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is just his second code. They are not asking for working code since they already have that, but instead an explanation on why the first doesn't work =)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
>
> for (li of lis){
>     li.addEventListener("click",()=>{
>         li.classList.toggle("remove");
>     })
> }
> ```

`li` is not a tag name (except inside the string on line one).

It is a variable name declared here:

> ```
> for (li of lis){
> ```

Since you didn't use `var`, `const`, or `let`, it is an implicit global.

Every event listener you are using is referring to the same global variable, which holds the last value you assigned to it.

You need to scope it (with `let`) so you get a unique variable for each iteration around the `for` loop (and thus for the arrow functions you pass to `addEventListener`).

```
for (let li of lis) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The iteration "assigns" each matching selected element to the "li" variable from first to last. By the time you click them the last element selected is the one assigned to the "li" variable (since it is overriding it each time). That's why when you click any of them it changes the last.
What you want is to reference the clicked element, not the "li" variable per se, hence the second code working (because it references the target of the "click" event)